# Ошибки при создании архива tar

Tags: linux, tar

При создании tar архива командой

```
tar -cf lk_patch.tar -T iss305_files_2018-10-31_1118.txt возвращается ошибка:

tar: bitrix/php_interface/include/functions.php\r: Функция stat завершилась с ошибкой: Нет такого файла или каталога
tar: local/components/portal/basket.full/templates/.default/script.js\r: Функция stat завершилась с ошибкой: Нет такого файла или каталога
tar: local/components/portal/manager.avatar/templates/.default/template.php\r: Функция stat завершилась с ошибкой: Нет такого файла или каталога
tar: Завершение работы с состоянием неисправности из-за возникших ошибок
```

Тогда как команда

```
tar -cf lk_patch.tar bitrix/php_interface/include/functions.php local/components/portal/basket.full/templates/.default/script.js local/components/portal/manager.avatar/templates/.default/ emplate.php local/components/portal/order/templates/.default/template.php
```

отрабатывает корректно.

Содержимое файла iss305_files_2018-10-31_1118.txt:

```
bitrix/php_interface/include/functions.php
local/components/portal/basket.full/templates/.default/script.js
local/components/portal/manager.avatar/templates/.default/template.php
local/components/portal/order/templates/.default/template.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

уберите `\r` из строк в файле командой

```
sed 's/\r//' -i iss305_files_2018-10-31_1118.txt
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё получилось.

Comment: @andrey.t Отметте решения как принятое, чтобы закрыть вопрос

Comment: *man dos2unix* perhaps?